# Best way to handle positioning in a website

Tags: html, css

My positioning of certain items on my web page keep moving slightly when i develop them on a big screen and display on a small screen they are out of position slightly, and vice versa.

this never happened me before but this is also the first site i am developing in asp.net here's my CSS

```
#backb{
  position:absolute;
  left :22%;
  bottom:10%;
 }

#backf{
  position:absolute;
  left :12%;
  bottom:0%;
 }

#avatar{
  position:absolute;
  left :55%;
  bottom:45%;
 }
```

Comment: Try adding overflow-y: scroll to the body

Comment: Why are you using position:absolute ?

Comment: *this never happened me before* - it happens to everyone once in a while, don't worry, buddy ... *chuckles*

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as best positioning while designing a page. You should use the techniques that are cross compatible across browsers and different systems.

In your CSS, you are using

```
position: absolute;
```

While using this style the element is positioned relative to its first positioned ancestor element. So, by default, its position will be relative to that of `<body>`.

Next, you are using `percentage(%)` values of assigning the different positions of the elements. This values are calculated by browser with respect to first relatively positioned ancestor, which is also by default `<body>`, so every time the resolution changes the template will shift accordingly.

---

Now, some pointers from me.

1. Do not use `position:absolute` unless its absolutely necessary.
2. Using percentage% values always lead to fluids result, so if you don't know how to handle it don't use it.

Comment: could you please point me in the right direction to fix the problem

Comment: @user1173371, for that upload an image of your required result(only layout, please omit internal things) and your layout markup. I will show it can be done without the position absolute and crazy percentage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your CSS is that you use percentages. Only use percentages if you know that the container you are taking X% of, is actually divisible by that number. Maybe you could try to use fixed widths. I also agree with the comments placed before: try to avoid position: absolute especially for the main components of your layout.

After writing CSS for a coulpe of years I have found that me and my collegues were reinventing the wheel over and over again and testing the main layout on all the different browsers was a pain in the ass. We concluded that it much easier to just trust the community and standardize on a framework. It will not work for 100% of your sites, but if you write CSS for many different clients it will suffice more than 90% of the time. I have looked at a couple of different frameworks and had my company of over 35 people standardize on the new version of YAML (http://www.yaml.de/). It has sped up development many times, but don;t take my word for it. Check out their excellent tutorial. I really is great. Cheers.